# Choosing an opamp for the amplifier stage of a signal generator (uses AD9833)

Tags: operational-amplifier, output, high-frequency, distortion, signal-generator

I am currently on a project to make my own signal generator for use in testing circuits etc. I have based it largely on a tutorial here: https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/projects/how-to-DIY-waveform-generator-analog-devices-ad9833-ATmega328p/

I aim for a frequency range of 1Hz to 1MHz, at least a maximum output of 12VPP and some dc offset capability.

The AD9833 DDS chip produces 600mV pp sine and triangle waves. The amplifier used in the tutorial uses LM318 which is unavailable where I live. The other option i have is the TL072. I have built a similar circuit to the one on the tutorial and managed to find an oscilloscope to look at the waveforms. Beyond 100KHz there is great distortions (sine waves look like triangle waves) but the measured frequency is similar to the set frequency even at 1MHz.

[image: Schematic of the circuit I built]

My first guess is that the opamp with its slew rate of 20V/us is not able to keep up at these frequencies and so I need to change the opamp. Unfortunately i do not have access to shops that sell RF like opmaps (100MHz capable). and most shops around sell general purpose components and a limited selection of audio stuff.

Any recommendations on the opmap to look for?
If my circuit is the limitation please point it out.

The shops around also sell components used in TV's, so if you know a suitable opamp and is used in TV's that would help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Asking for components meeting certain properties is **Off topic**. Find a component yourself using parametric search, learn how to do that by watching: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zqlAq266aTs

Comment: *My first guess is that the opamp with its slew rate of 20V/us is not able to keep up at these frequencies and so I need to change the opamp* And I'm just going to state here that the slew rate is fine. Now prove me wrong with **facts** and **numbers**. There should be no guessing. You can just calculate what slew rate you need, so calculate it.

Comment: 12 volts p-p at 1 MHz for a triangle wave implies a slew rate of 12 volts per 0.5 microseconds or 24 volts per microsecond. I think you then need to consider what a sinewave will need.

Comment: Thanks for the link.

Comment: For the sine wave i get a slew rate required of 37V/us. This is not much higher than 20V/us but i do not see any other possible reason for the distortion

Comment: Any more constructive criticism is welcomed

Answer (score 2):

A slew rate of 37.7 volts per microsecond is what a 12 volt p-p sinewave at 1 MHz produces. So, realistically, you should be looking for an op-amp that is typically rated at 45 volts per μs.

You must also take into account that the gain your first op-amp has is (maybe) 15 and that means, for a decent reproduction of a sine wave at 1 MHz, you need an op-amp with a gain-bandwidth product of significantly more than 15 MHz, possibly 30 MHz.

However, for a 1 MHz triangle wave to be reproduced reasonably accurately you'll need to account for the triangle wave's harmonics. So, maybe something around 300 MHz gain-bandwidth product for half-decent reproduction.

> *Unfortunately i do not have access to shops that sell RF like opmaps
> (100MHz capable).*

That might be a problem. It would also be a significant problem for an LM318 and certainly a problem for the TL072.